# F# - Return Float Array to Excel Using Excel-DNA - Only First Value Displayed

Tags: f#, array-formulas, excel-dna

I am trying to display (using an array formula) an F# and Excel-DNA returned float array but, though I can see the correct result in the "Function Arguments" dialog box, only the first value is displayed in the selected range. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like Excel-DNA is returning a row array so to convert it to a column array, I need to use `TRANSPOSE()` in Excel.

Comment: Yes - you can also return an Array2D with many rows and one column.